# pre select a value in an PrimeVue Dropdown component not working

Tags: vue.js, dropdown, primevue

I want dropdown value to be selected by default based on values stored in `user` state coming from `userToUpdate` prop, i checked `user.gender` value and it holds the value `female`, `optionValue` binding didn't help.

```
const props = defineProps(["userToUpdate"]);

const user = reactive({
  gender: props.userToUpdate.gender
})

      <Dropdown
        id="gender"
        :options="['Male', 'Female']"
        placeholder="Select Gender"
        class="p-0"
        :optionValue = "user.gender"
        v-model="user.gender"
      
      />
```

Comment: It's case sensitive, so `female` does not match the option `Female`.

Comment: @yoduh that explains it, and you also don't need to use ```optionValue```, ```v-model``` is enough